# Image_picker not giving real path of the image in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, imagepicker

I want to select image from gallery, but when I tried to save it in shared preferences. I found that image_picker gives temporary location like **tmp/image_picker_4415467867A964-791E-4AFA995BA-18295-0003861F9255294A.jpg**

This is not real path of the image. How should I get original location path of the image for later use?

Or I want to save the whole image in database.. what to do?
pickimage() is deprecated now?

Please help

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Fluter demo',
  debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
    visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
  ),
  home: MyHomePage(),
);
 }
 }

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  File _image;
  String _imageloc;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    LoadImage();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Image Picker'),
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            _imageloc != null
                ? CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: FileImage(File(_imageloc)),
                radius: 80,
              )
            : CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: _image != null
                    ? FileImage(_image)
                    : NetworkImage(
                        'https://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/320000/velka/background-image.png'),
              ),
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              PickImage();
            },
            child: Text('Pick Image'),
          ),
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            saveImage(_image.path);
          },
          child: Text('saved'),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
  }

  void PickImage() async {
    var image = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
print(image.path);
setState(() {
  _image = image;
});
  }

  void saveImage(_imageloc) async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      preferences.setString('imageloc', _imageloc);
    });
  }

  void LoadImage() async {
    SharedPreferences saveimage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      saveimage.getString('imageloc');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably should write more of your code. Like where are you running the code? What have you tried so far and so on. With code examples-

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. I will post it later.. my system not working now

Comment: I have posted my code

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you need the image later, you need to *copy* it and save it somewhere. The actual image, not just the path. If I select an image in your app, I want it to be saved. I don't want it to be gone when I delete the picture from my gallery, or switch phones.

The path you have is sufficient to read the image and save it wherever you want. Your backend most likely, since I want to have my picture, even on another phone.

How you do this is highly dependent on your specific backend, but I'm sure there will be a tutorial for it.

Comment: Thanks.. but what if I want to save it later and at the same time, I want to show it to user?

Comment: Show temporary file or copied file?

Comment: You can show it to the user based on the temporary filename, but once they hit save, I'd upload it somewhere.

Comment: Save image in database (format?) or copy it and save into filesystem. Which is better?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with it. If you want to show it later I guess saving it to a filesystem that is served by a webserver might make sense. If it's sensitive information, maybe putting it into a secured database is better. Copying it to the local device is probably not what your users expect from the app.

Comment: I just want to show image when they selected and save  it for later. But only in their device and that's not a sensitive information.